# Is it possible to write a shell command that connects to Heroku and runs a Ruby command?

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, shell, heroku

Is it possible to script the following on OSX?

```
heroku run console
load 'init.rb'
```

The following does ***not*** work:

```
alias 'heroku_init=heroku run console; load "init.rb"'
```

It seems that the shell has to wait for the Heroku console to connect, or needs a way to send the `load` command to the Heroku console instead of the bash shell.

Comment: Would something like this work? `heroku run irb init.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big ups to camilo-santana for the answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn heroku console
expect "irb(main):001:0>"
send "load 'app/init.rb'\r"
interact
```

It can also be done with an alias:

```
alias 'hc=heroku run console -- -r ./app/init.rb'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want it to send `load 'init.rb'` to the standard input of the `heroku run console` program. You do that in the shell using the pipe operator:

```
echo "load 'init.rb'" | heroku run console
```

This works but notice it makes the console hang, if you want to input some more commands manually you can do:

```
{ echo "load 'init.rb'"; cat } | heroku run console
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: The first example does work but makes console hang. The second one doesn't work for me. This seems like a good solution if the console doesn't hang.

Comment: I'm running on ubuntu, I think OSX uses bash as well, what output do you get with `echo $0`?

Comment: No error, I just get a `>` prompt. Then I hit ctrl-c and it goes back to the bash prompt, but nothing happens.