# How can we run the "ssh -keygen" command using ssh module

Tags: ansible

I want to create the private and public keys on the servers, when i do it manually, it asks me to press "enter" thrice and need to select "y" once. can i run the same command using ansible? if yes, how to manage the "enter" which we press manually while we run it on server.  Any help will be great to proceed.

below is the playbook i tried

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - name: "Run ssh commands to create new ssh keys"
     shell: ssh-keygen -f /home/dp794d/id_rsa -t rsa -q -N ""
     args:
       creates: /home/dp794d/.ssh/id_rsa
     with_lines: cat "/home/capio/ansible/pmossWipm/day1/logs/testIP.txt"
```

and i am getting the below error -

```
failed: [localhost] (item=130.6.50.132) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "ssh-keygen -f /home/dp794d/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -q -N \"\"", "delta": "0:00:00.248041", "end": "2017-04-26 14:41:36.361705", "failed": true, "item": "130.6.50.132", "rc": 1, "start": "2017-04-26 14:41:36.113664", "stderr": "open /home/dp794d/.ssh/id_rsa failed: Permission denied.", "stdout": "Saving the key failed: /home/dp794d/.ssh/id_rsa.", "stdout_lines": ["Saving the key failed: /home/dp794d/.ssh/id_rsa."], "warnings": []}
```

Comment: `"stderr": "open /home/dp794d/.ssh/id_rsa failed: Permission denied."` - I think you have filesystem permission issues, e.g. when `~/.ssh` is accidentally root-owned (and is 0700) and your playbook connects as a normal user.

Answer (score 2):

it seems you have a two-fold issue

1. A`Permission denied` to `/home/dp794d/.ssh/id_rsa`

   - you'll get this when user running playbook doesn't have access to the above file or directory. Consider using, `become:` to fix this context mismatch.
2. Keyboard entry

   - I just helped a friend with [using expect script for automated keyboard entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764335/is-it-possible-to-write-a-shell-command-that-connects-to-heroku-and-runs-a-ruby/43645636#43645636). Perhaps you could modify that to suit your needs.
   - `ssh-keygen` can run non-interactively with the `-N new_passphrase` option. try:

     `ssh-keygen -t rsa -N '' -f foo.rsa`

Note: try with single or double-quotes until you get the desired effect.

Comment: thanks for the help, it worked fine!!
Really appreciated :)

Comment: cool. if this helped you, mark it as solved so others can find it easier (and i get some much-needed rep points so i can interact more on this site).